# Can someone explain to me how this code works please?

Tags: c#

The point of this code is to create a function which returns the number of true values in an array. So if someone were to input an array that's `[true, false, true, false]` the ouput would be 2. I didn't create this code, this is one of the code solutions for this practice problem on a site called edabit. I'm new to coding, can someone explain how inputting `val => val` into `arr.Count()` returns only the number of true values? Thanks.

```
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static int CountTrue(bool[] arr) {
        return arr.Count(val => val);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`.  Read more here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `return arr.Count(val => val);` means `return arr.Count(val => val == true);`. Which means "for each element `val` in the array `arr`, count the ones that are `== true`".

Comment: It's also a shorter way of expressing `arr.Where(val => val).Count()` or `arr.Where(val => val == true).Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would understand it better if written like this

```
arr.Count(val => val == true);
```

Predicate `val` is equivalent to `val == true`

This `Count` overload takes as parameter a function to test each element for a condition. It will filter those where condition returns `true` and count them.

Answer (score 0):

`Count` iterates through each item and increments the Count if the expression is true. To expand what it's doing:

```
public static int CountTrue(bool[] arr)
{
    return arr.Count(val => val == true);
}
```

To count the number of false values, you would do the following:

```
public static int CountFalse(bool[] arr)
{
    return arr.Count(val => val == false);
}
```

Comment: For `CountFalse` you could also use `arr.Count(val => !val)`.